# Generic type in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-form

I am having problem understanding the below code from [`redux-form`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-form/lib/selectors.d.ts)

```
export type DataSelector<FormData = {}, State = {}> = (formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState) => (state: State) => FormData;

export const getFormValues: DataSelector;
```

```
// mapState
const values = getFormValues("formName")(state) // {}
return { form: values }
```

The IDE is giving me error that `values` is returning `{}`. Which is expected because `State = {}`. However, I want to use the access the `values.name`. Is there a way to pass in `FormData` or `State`?

Comment: More code. I can't run these code.

Comment: `FormData = {}` means it will be an empty object. You can update your type to `FormData = { name: string }`

Comment: @Rajesh but it's 3rd party library (redux-form), how can I update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const getFormValues: DataSelector` always sets the default type `{}` for the generic type parameters `FormData` and `State`, as the function does not forward those parameters to consumers.

The usual way to solve a type issue involving a third party library is: If you can't control it, wrap it. Meaning, define your own function which wraps the libary function and narrows to the desired project types.

```
// your own types
type MyFormData = { baz: string };
type MyState = {foo: number};

function getFormValuesWrapper(state: MyState): MyFormData {
  return getFormValues("formName")(state) as MyFormData;
}

// or keep it generic
function getFormValuesWrapper2<FormData, State>(state: State){
  return getFormValues("formName")(state) as FormData
}

const values = getFormValuesWrapper(state);
values.baz // (property) baz: string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBDGGDKwA2wAxjNADwBi0AtptnALxwDeAvgDRw7YypNsA+RnAAUAKDhwAZjQByGasABccAM4woASwB2AczEBKRkJHqsyrj2BGGQqlFpYMAbjFiA9O7ihIsOEQhtdThdYBh7agA1DHwAV2BVFTpcAmJSKFcAE2J8DChUAKD4UPCaaLiEpKc8QhJoVzFC4LNeYWZpCAgVAEY4VgakFDgAWUQI5La4ACMMAC8VdS09PtdB1FHuczaZLrhtWOop4Ch+t09pWO0STUCQsIjy+NUAdSgMMBQoShpkzk3eASmKwqf7WZgeLySfIwWJQbR3UoOR4JEQAIhkDnkilRBiB5iMGFUcHGTghfTcUku11uJQeMSer3enzxvBUGysBjZYx+ThYEjg0Nh8NpZXpKPRcgUwBxLOscEJI25DmSrlYbia8AAbmKiUwRUidYyPsdZQYGtqKqoAHQzWZiIA)